# "Unexpected token import" as error when creating new react-native project

Tags: react-native

I am creating a new react-native project using :

```
react-native init {proj_name}
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
D:\Reactnative\Project\{proj_name}\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cliEntry.js:30
import type {CommandT} from './commands';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Module._compile (D:\Reactnative\Project\Learnwizz\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:91:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\Reactnative\Project\Learnwizz\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:96:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a known bug right now with react-native 0.56 when running on Windows (see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19669) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/181)).

Until it is fixed, you can work around the issue by explicitly specifying an older version of react-native when running react-native init. E.g.

`react-native init {proj_name} --version react-native@0.55.4`

Comment: How to use run-android command with this? I'm trying react-native run android --version react-native@0.55.4, unsuccessfully.

Comment: @JhonatanPereira - I don't think you have to specify react-native version when using react-native run-android. It should only be used when you are creating the project using react-native init.

Comment: Understood, but I'm seeing the error yet... In an existing project, while I'm trying run application :(

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** As a temporary workaround, you can init your project with the previous version of RN using `react-native init --version="0.55.4" {projectName}`

I'm also running into this exact error today. I just now noticed `react-native init` is now using react-native 0.56 which was just [release a few hours ago](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.56.0) I believe.

This might give you some troubleshooting ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am getting Exception in latest version that is 0.56 (React Native) and not able to run the code in emulator, However I have downgraded React native version to 0.55.4, then it is working for me..

### Run Below line of command :

```
react-native init {project_name} --version react-native@0.55.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with new version of react-native , typescript code in react-cli has some issue , but don't worry 
go to app folder
hit command

```
npm uninstall react-native --save
npm install react-native@0.55.4 --save
```

will solve your problem !!

Answer (score 0):

in windows 10 update **node.js** to version **14.18.1**

https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.1/node-v14.18.1-x64.msi