# `react-native init app` is not working in React-Native 0.56

Tags: react-native, npm-install, react-native-cli

React Native 0.56

I have already installed `react-native-cli globally`, and when I try to create a new project using `react-native init myapp` , I'm getting an error.

This is the error I face.

[image: screenshot]

> env:-  windows 10,node version v10.1.0, npm version 6.1.0, react native version 0.56

Previous projects are working well,but not able to create a new one.

Comment: Which error? ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug on react-native version 0.56 
Try `react-native init [YourProject] --version react-native@0.55.4` to init the older version

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178688/error-creating-new-react-native-project)

Answer (score 1):

install watchman in Ubuntu you can do it, it will be solved your problem to creat RN APP +< 56  :

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman/
$ git checkout v4.7.0
$ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev
$ ./autogen.sh 
$ ./configure 
$ make
$ sudo make install

$ watchman --version
$ echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches  && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a  /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee  -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman  shutdown-server
```