# Error creating a React Native project - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: windows, react-native, cmd

In trying to create a project with native Code, my Windows command prompt always shows me the error message below at the end of the creation which makes the React Native project folder is not complete and I can not so do not launch the application from my Android emulator. Does anyone have a solution to solve this problem? Thank you in advance (Sorry if my English is bad, I speak French).

Console text: https://pastecode.xyz/view/23e2e986

```
C:\Users\Quentin SAVEAN\Desktop\ApiApp\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cliEntry.js:30
import type {CommandT} from './commands';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Module._compile (C:\Users\Quentin SAVEAN\Desktop\ApiApp\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:91:24)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\Quentin SAVEAN\Desktop\ApiApp\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:96:7)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
```

Regards,

Quentin S.

Comment: Tu veux créer un projet react native ? Tu as suivit le titi de Facebook ?

Comment: @tetar Oui, j'arrive à créer un projet react-native avec la commande "react-native init AwesomeProject" mais j'ai toujours une erreur à la fin de l'installation dans mon invite de commande (cmd) qui est celle afficher sur mon premier post .

Comment: Essaye d’installer git desktop pour avoir un bon terminal sur Windows (tu fais clic droit -> git bash here pour ouvrir ) ensuite vérifie ton install de node et de npm et si ça marche toujours pas essaye de télécharger une app déjà existante et regarde si tu peux la lancer.si tu as besoin je t’en fais une sur mon git et tu la clone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178688/error-creating-new-react-native-project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178688/error-creating-new-react-native-project

Comment: @tetar Cela semble être un problème de version React Native. En essayant avec la version 0.55.4, mon projet fonctionne mais avec la dernière version sa ne fonctionne pas ce qui m'embête un peu d'un côté car je suis obligé d'utiliser vielle version. Pour ce qui est de node et de npm, ils sont bien installés voici leurs versions : node :  v8.11.3 - npm: 5.6.0

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174014/room on va parler la

Comment: @tetar Je suis nouveau sur le forum et il me faut 20 réputations pour pouvoir discuter dans le Tchat room.

Comment: du coup go discord