# How to solve this react native error?

Tags: android, react-native, babeljs

```
import type {CommandT} from './commands';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Module._compile (C:\projects\splashdemo\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:91:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\projects\splashdemo\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:96:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
PS C:\projects\splashdemo>
```

- I have created this project with this command

  `react-native init {proj_name} --version react-native@0.55.4`
- Now while execute this command in my terminal, I got this issue :

  `react-native run-android`

please suggest some solution for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error creating new react-native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178688/error-creating-new-react-native-project)

Comment: I am getting this issue while run this project not while creating @TomTom

Comment: Which version of node are you using ? And is this on a windows machine ?

Comment: node version 8.11.3 & npm version 6.1.0, even though I tried with lower down the npm version 5.6.0 still this command is not working @TomTom

Comment: try 
      import {CommandT} from './commands';